# Find upper bounds for ‎$‎\frac{1}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-n+2m-2}}‎$‎.‎

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

> My ‎question ‎is‎ ‎to find upper bounds for ‎the ‎following ‎fraction ‎(I ‎mean what ‎will ‎be ‎question ‎mark)‎
>   ‎\begin{align*}‎‎‎|\frac{1}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-n+2m-2}}|\leq \;?,\end{align*}‎
>   where ‎‎$‎‎\beta‎‎\simeq 0.7‎$, ‎‎$‎1\leq m\leq ‎\frac{n}{2}‎$, $0\leq n\leq N ‎‎$ and ‎$m, ‎n, N\in‎\mathbb{N}‎$ ‎ ($n$ is even).

‎To this purpose, I tried to find the minimum and maximum of the denominator as follows

‎Since ‎$2^{‎\beta‎-n+2m-2} \leq 2^{‎\beta‎+2m-2}‎‎$‎, ‎then ‎we ‎have‎ ‎‎$‎
1-2^{‎\beta‎-n+2m-2} \geq 1-2^{‎\beta‎+2m-2}$‎. ‎So ‎we ‎have‎‎
‎‎\begin{align*}\frac{1}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-n+2m-2}}\leq ‎‎\frac{1}{1-2^{‎\beta‎+2m-2}}‎‎‎‎\end{align*}‎‎‎‎‎‎
Now is the following correct?
‎‎\begin{align*}‎‎|‎‎‎\frac{1}{1-2^{‎\beta‎-n+2m-2}}|\leq ‎\frac{1}{2^{-‎\beta-2m+2}}\end{align*}‎‎
If not, does there exist any bound for my fraction? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let do this:
$$m \leqslant \frac{n}{2} \Longrightarrow -n + 2m \leqslant 0 \Longrightarrow \beta - n + 2m -2 \leqslant \beta - 2 \Longrightarrow 2^{\beta - n + 2m -2} \leqslant 2^{\beta - 2} \Longrightarrow$$
$$ \Longrightarrow 1 - 2^{\beta - n + 2m -2} \geqslant 1 - 2^{\beta - 2} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{1 - 2^{\beta - n + 2m -2}} \leqslant \frac{1}{1 - 2^{\beta - 2}} < \frac{1}{1 - 2^{0.8 - 2}} < 1.8 $$
So $N$ has no influence on it. And as approximation of $\max\beta$ become closer to its real value, the achieved bound become closer to the fraction.

Comment: @ Ali Ashja', thanks for your answer firstly. It seems your answer found a bound, but I looked for some bounds respect to $m$ and less than yours.

Comment: You set $n=0$ and let $m$ be free to get some $\max$ respect to $m$, that was incorrect! Because $n=0$ implies $m=0$ too. So your $\max$ is, in fact, less than real $\max$.